# Connecting Docker mongo cluster from my local machine

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have created a mongodb replica in docker on my local machine. After configuration, replica is working if I connect inside the containers. Then when I connect localhost:30001,30002,30003 from my machine but outside the container, it says connection failed, prompting the following error message.

```
SERVER [node1:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN)
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Unknown host: node3

SERVER [node2:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Unknown host: node2

SERVER [node1:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Unknown host: node1
```

Here is my docker-comopse file

```
version: '3'
services:
  node1:
    image: mongo
    container_name: "node1"
    networks:
      - mongocluster
    ports:
      - 30001:27017
    command: mongod  --dbpath /data/db --replSet repset
  node2:
    image: mongo
    container_name: "node2"
    networks:
      - mongocluster
    ports:
      - 30002:27017
    command: mongod  --dbpath /data/db --replSet repset
    depends_on:
      - node1
  node3:
    image: mongo
    container_name: "node3"
    networks:
      - mongocluster
    ports:
      - 30003:27017
    command: mongod  --dbpath /data/db --replSet repset
    depends_on:
      - node2
networks:
  mongocluster:
    driver: bridge
```

And this is how I configured the cluster in mongodb

```
config = {
  "_id": "repset",
  "members": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "host": "node1:27017"
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "host": "node2:27017"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "host": "node3:27017"
    }
  ]
}
```

I understand my local machine cannot interpret IP for node1, node2 and node3. I am only using it for dev purpose, so what is the quickest (maybe dirty) way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following links help:

[mongodb-replica-set-with-docker-and-connecting-net-core-app](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/setting-up-a-mongodb-replica-set-with-docker-and-connecting-to-it-with-a--net-core-app)

[mongo-replica-set-docker-localhost](http://37yonub.ru/articles/mongo-replica-set-docker-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. Mongo's Replica set self-reports node1,2,3 as an IP address and your client from outside of the container network tries [unsuccessfully] to reach these.

One easy way to fix it would be to put your client inside the container within the same docker network.

Another [dirty] option - adjust hosts file on your local machine to interpret nodeX as the localhost. You'll need to tweak the port numbers to, so host and container port numbers are the same (start mongo on 30001,2,3 in the container)

And perhaps the easiest one - forget about replica set and just run the standalone mongo container.